# Show 'Read more' in rss feed

Tags: posts, rss, feed

How can I show 'Read more' links in rss feed instead of showing excerpt? The settings in reading only allow to choose between full content and excerpt.

Comment: RSS feed only sends excerpt and never the full article. And an RSS feed don't have a `read-more` link. But do you want a `read-more link ` for your article listing? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Do you really need a 'read more'? Anyone able to use an RSS reader will know to click on the title to read the rest.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic - That's a good point, I just wanted it to look the same as the blog itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but you shouldn't.

RSS feeds are built in XML.  Not in HTML.  Links in XML don't have meaning because they're HTML elements.  However, because XML can be read by most HTML parsers (i.e. web browsers), you can easily mistake an XML document for an HTML one (the prevalence of XHTML helps to blur this line even further).

In reality, though, no one actually reads a raw XML feed.  They open the feed in a web browser and let the browser parse it into something intelligible.  Firefox and Safari are very good at this actually.  Or they open it in an eternal feed aggregator like Google Reader.

All of these other applications will parse the content permalink (your post's url) and use it as a contextual reference for the post.  In some cases, they'll add the "read more" link for you.  In others, they'll convert the title to a click-able link in the display.

In either case, you're relying on the *reader* to generate the link, not on the rendered content of your post.

For example, here is the feed for my blog - http://mindsharestrategy.com/feed - rendered by Safari.  The browser has both turned the title into a link *and* automatically added a "Read More ..." link to the bottom of each post.

[image: Blog feed in Safari web browser]

The key thing to remember is that this feed is a raw XML document that was parsed automatically by the browser.  I did not specify any of the styling, colors, or even the Read More link ... Safari did that all on its own.  Firefox actually only displays an excerpt for each post rather than the full post content (each followed by an auto-generated "Read More" link).  Google Reader does something very similar, as will most other feed aggregators.

Answer (score 3):

You could choose to show the summary (excerpt) in the feed and adding this to your theme's functions.php:

```
function moreFeedlink( $content ) {
    $content = $content . '<div><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Read More</a></div>';
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', 'moreFeedlink' );
```

Comment: This displays before the View More link not after it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to reading settings and select 'full text' for what to show readers in a feed:
[image]

Comment: I have already tried it but it shows full text instead of breaking it at 'more' shortcode

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the  function but that might change how your posts are displayed on site, not sure as been a while since I've used the  function!

Might be worth a scan through this - http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More